# C++ Derived classes of both owner and children classes

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, inheritance

So Suppose I have a animal class managed by zoo class.

```
Animal is an abstract class to be derived by other real animal classes
class Animal{
public:
  Animal();
  virtual ~Animal() = 0;
  //Various animal related functions
}

class Zoo{
public:
  Zoo();
  virtual ~Zoo();
  virtual void updateAll();
  //And various other functions dealing with animals
private:
  vector<animal*> animals
}
```

Now say I want to create a bird_zoo, and I want to reuse most of the code 
used in Zoo class and Animal class.

So I make bird class

```
class Bird : public Animal{
public:
  Bird();
  virtual ~Bird();
  //all the various functions derived from Animal class
  virtual void fly(); //New function that Animal didn't have
}

class Bird_Zoo : public Zoo{
public:
  Bird_Zoo();
  virtual ~Bird_Zoo();
  //And various other functions dealing with animals, derived from Zoo
  virtual void flyAll(); //New function that Zoo didn't have
private:
  //vector<??????> birds
}
```

How do I have this `Bird_Zoo` function deal with the Birds it has?
If I stay with `vector<Animal*>` from the Zoo class, how can I call `fly()`?
Do I really have to cast it to `Bird*` every time?
Is there way to conceptually "overload" `vector<Animal*>` as `vector<Bird*>`,
so that all the old Zoo function will still work fine?

Thank you.

Comment: animals is private in Zoo, so you can't use it in Bird_Zoo anyhow, with or without casting.  Maybe you meant to use protected?

Comment: It it makes sense, you could keep using `Zoo` (but with `proctected` vector `animals` and add a static cast to `Bird*` in the interface.

Comment: psusi//Yes. I meant to use protected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One other possibility would be to use templates.

```
class Zoo {
  // ...
  virtual void updateAll() = 0;
};

template <typename T,
          typename = typename enable_if<is_base_of<Animal, T>::value>::type>
class ZooWithAVector : public AbstractZoo {
public:
  virtual void updateAll() { /* ... */ }
  // Various functions dealing with T-animals
private:
  vector<T*> animals;
};

typedef ZooWithAVector<Animal> TypicalZoo;

class BirdZoo : public ZooWithAVector<Bird> {
  virtual void flyAll() { /* work with the vector<Bird> */ }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you to not have a `vector<animal*>` member in `Zoo`. A base class (especially an abstract one) should only implement what is in common for all potential derived classes.

Instead you could have a `General_Zoo` extending `Zoo` class which could handle all types of animals. So `General_Zoo` would be a sibling class of `Bird_Zoo`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. But it's just that I really want to reuse the code used in Zoo (which involves Animals), because Bird_Zoo is nearly identical with Zoo, with just few more Bird specific functions.

Comment: @jaehoony: As a rule of thumb, don't use inheritance for code reuse.  Composition is almost always better suited for that task.

Answer (score 1):

Your design is faulty. Theoretically, you'd think that a `Bird_Zoo` **is-a** `Zoo`. And it is. But not the way you modeled it.

You see, in your design, a `Zoo` contains a collection of any kind of `Animal`, whereas a `Bird_Zoo` does not. So, if you chose to model it like this, a `Bird_Zoo` is no longer a `Zoo`.

You can either not use inheritance for this, or, what I would do, remove the `vector<Animal*>` from the base class.

Comment: I think your logic is 100% correct, and I agree. But you must also see my dilemma here. I want to Zoo and Bird_Zoo reuse/share the code that deals with Animals, because they have a lot of overlaps, and I feel there has to be some way to do this, because Bird is-a Animal. Do you think there's a way to do this? It's okay to redesign the whole thing.

Comment: @jaehoony I'm sure the basic logic can be overriden even like this.